# Timestamp to string conversion dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to convert a timestamp to a human readable string in (scala) spark dataframe and do the following:

```
df.select(
        $"ts",
        to_date(from_unixtime($"ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd").as("date"),
        to_date(from_unixtime($"ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd-hh").as("date2")
      ).limit(10)
       .show(false)
```

And get the following:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
|ts        |date      |date2|
+----------+----------+-----+
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
|1605628105|2020-11-17|null |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Why can't I extract the hour from the timestamp? Why does it yield null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_date` will only give you date but not other values like hour, minutes. To get hour value use `date_format` function.

```
df.select(
        $"ts",
        to_date(from_unixtime($"ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd").as("date"),
        date_format(from_unixtime($"ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd-hh").as("date2") // Added date_format.
)
.limit(10)
.show(false)
```